# SQL - Obtener calculo de filas con Alias

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Ejecutivo as Nombre, 
SUM(plan_il * 15) as pi, 
SUM(plan_mo * 5) as pm 
FROM tablename group by Nombre
```

Mi problema es que quiero agrega una suma de estos nuevos calculo algo as

```
SELECT Ejecutivo as Nombre, 
SUM(plan_il * 15) as pi, 
SUM(plan_mo * 5) as pm,
(pi + pm) as total //<< Obtener total
FROM tablename group by Nombre
```

Pero no me funciona, mysql me tira el siguiente error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(pi + pm) as total
```

Alguien sabe como puedo obtener el valor de estas nuevas filas para hacer el calculo.

Answer (score 2):

Generalmente, no puedes utilizar el alias que le has puesto a una columna para hacer cálculos con ella.

La primera solución, es realizar de nuevo el cálculo de cada columna para hacerlo, en tu caso, podría ser:

```
SELECT Ejecutivo as Nombre, 
       SUM(plan_il * 15) as pi, 
       SUM(plan_mo * 5) as pm 
       SUM(plan_il * 15) + SUM(plan_mo * 5) as Total
  FROM tablename 
 group by Nombre;
```

Usualmente, también, los motores son lo suficientemente inteligente para no repetir todos los cálculos, así que el efecto en el desempeño es el mismo.

Otra posible solución es utilizar un CTE, depende de la versión del motor que utilices, va a estar soportado.

Por ejemplo:

```
with
Q as (
SELECT Ejecutivo as Nombre, 
       SUM(plan_il * 15) as pi, 
       SUM(plan_mo * 5) as pm 
  FROM tablename 
 group by Nombre
)
select Nombre, pi, pm, pi + pm as Total
  from Q;
```

Comment: Dirias tu, que la primera opción a pesar de que se repitan los datos siguen teniendo un buen performance?

Comment: Si, no me atrevo a generalizar pero, en mi experiencia, en versiones modernas de los principales motores, tiende a ser equivalente.